# Possible misuse of comma operator here

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I'm getting warnings in Xcode after updating to the recommended pod settings.  The warning is

```
Possible misuse of comma operator here
```

with a suggested fix of

```
Cast expression to void to silence warning
```

The warnings occur in leveldb-library/db/c.cc at the start and limit keys:

```
void leveldb_compact_range(
    leveldb_t* db,
    const char* start_key, size_t start_key_len,
    const char* limit_key, size_t limit_key_len) {
  Slice a, b;
  db->rep->CompactRange(
      // Pass NULL Slice if corresponding "const char*" is NULL
      (start_key ? (a = Slice(start_key, start_key_len), &a) : NULL),
      (limit_key ? (b = Slice(limit_key, limit_key_len), &b) : NULL));
}
```

Has anyone else had the same or know what's causing it?  I'm running Cocoapods 1.2.0.

Comment: If you want to disable this warning you can do it by [disabling the "Suspicious Commas" warning in your Build Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37026478/111307)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

leveldb now builds without warnings after a `pod update` to version 1.20 of the leveldb-library CocoaPod.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! The update installed with 16 new errors but after a subsequent clean, all errors and warnings are gone

Comment: One small thing the upgrade numbering for the database seems to go backwards... Installing FirebaseDatabase 4.1.0 (was 4.1.1)

Comment: @ShaneO'Seasnain The version shouldn't go backwards. Check your Podfile.lock, pod deintegrate, etc. If you're still seeing and can make a repro, please report to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me.

Code:

```
 if (++keyIndexValue == [self.str length])
    keyIndexValue = 0, keyPtr = keyData;
```

I've solved it by splitting the statements over multiple lines within the "if" condition:

"If at end of key data, reset count and set key pointer back to start of key value"

```
if (++keyIndexValue == [self.str length])
{
   keyIndexValue = 0;
   keyPtr = keyData;
}
```

Comment: It seems this is what Apple wanted, but I have to say they shouldn't force us to add { squiggly brackets } around an if-block where we knew what we were doing

Comment: The other way to do it (which looks really messy) would be to cast the left operand to `operator,` to void, like this: `(void)(keyIndexValue = 0), keyPtr = keyData;`

Answer (score 1):

We are aware of the warning, we'll update the version once the leveldb fixes the issue. For now you can ignore the warnings.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the heads up